# Time complexity of %in% in R; is there a way to make it O(1) like with sets in Python?

Tags: r, time-complexity, complexity-theory

The `%in%` operator in R checks if something is in something else, kind of obviously.  But I'm curious about the performance.  In Python, searching for an item a set or dict keys is O(1) because the set is hash table, I think.  But searching for an item in a list in Python could be O(n) with an n-length list, because it will search element-by-element.  So how is `%in%` working behind the scenes for different datatypes in R?  It seems to take 5 times longer to search for something in a factor dtype in R as opposed to a vector, but it seems like `%in%` searches a vector linearly.  At first I thought a factor datatype might be like a set in Python, since they both reduce something to it's unique values, but not at all: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_data_types.htm.  Here is some example code so you can see what I mean with the runtimes:

```
library(microbenchmark)
s <- seq(5000)
microbenchmark(1 %in% s, times = 100000)
# searching for a term further in the list takes longer
microbenchmark(4999 %in% s, times = 100000)
s <- as.factor(s)
# searching for something in a factor takes way longer than a vector
# I think because everything is converted to a character dtype
microbenchmark(4999 %in% s, times = 100000)
```

My main question is this: is there a way to make %in% O(1) in R?  A related question: is there an equivalent (in R) of the set() datatype in Python?

Comment: Note: the docs for %in% are here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html  it is the match() function.  Hard to find actually.

Comment: You can use environments as a poor-man's hash, since the objects are allegedly internally hashed. You can also use [`hashmap`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hashmap/index.html) which hashes things in a vectorizable fashion (unlike environments) but cannot store arbitrary objects (which environments can do).

Comment: Are you trying to start a flame war? Look, depending on your need, environments might fit them, in which case *yes, there is an inherent datatype in R*. Is there a pragmatic need for this *O(1)* efficiency, or is this mostly pedagogic as you learn R?

Comment: No, I'm trying to efficiently check if something is in a set of items in R.  I've used it before in Python for projects.  I've looped through things checking if they are in a set and skipping them if so.  If the set is large, looking through a list or vector is slow.

Comment: And R has some advantages over Python, but like I said, I think Python wins this particular round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, there *is* an inherent set-like mechanism in R, though it is admittedly a little hackish and perhaps not quite what was intended. (Some of the limitations of this hack are documented in the [`hashmap`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hashmap/index.html) package.)

Environments in R are internally hashed. This can be used for storage of arbitary objects with random access (both read and write). To check some benchmarks, I'll generate a few types of vectors to substantiate your initial concern and show the improvement using environments can make.

We'll first generate some similar data, ordered in various fashions to highlight an issue you brought up:

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(2)
s1 <- seq(5000)
s2 <- rev(s1) # to highlight the bias you highlighted, since the vector is sorted
s3 <- sample(s1) # to shake things up a little
s4 <- as.character(s3) # comparison with character-based named in 'l' and 'e'

l <- list()
e <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
for (i in s4) {
  assign(i, TRUE, envir = e)
  l[[i]] <- TRUE
}
head(names(l)) # unordered
# [1] "925"  "3512" "2866" "840"  "4716" "4713"
```

The `list` does have ordinality within its objects, which supports the assumption that its objects are *not* hashed:

```
which(names(l) == "1")
# [1] 2291
```

Environments do not have this:

```
e[[1]]
# Error in e[[1]] : wrong arguments for subsetting an environment
```

Some quick membership testing: I used a logical for the value, though that is completely arbitary. Anything other than `NULL` would suffice for our needs here. We'll use a simple `!is.null(e[[...]])` to test for specific membership:

```
!is.null(e[["1"]])
# [1] TRUE
!is.null(e[["10000"]])
# [1] FALSE
!is.null(l[["1"]])
# [1] TRUE
!is.null(l[["10000"]])
# [1] FALSE

microbenchmark(
  vec1 =  1  %in% s1,
  vec2 =  1  %in% s2,
  vec3 =  1  %in% s3,
  vec4 = "1" %in% s4,
  lst = is.null(l[["1"]]),
  env = is.null(e[["1"]]),
  times = 1000
)
# Warning in microbenchmark(vec1 = 1 %in% s1, vec2 = 1 %in% s2, vec3 = 1 %in%  :
#   Could not measure a positive execution time for 6 evaluations.
# Unit: nanoseconds
#  expr   min    lq     mean median    uq     max neval
#  vec1  5835  6929 12493.25   7294  9482 3214588  1000
#  vec2  9117  9847 16660.73  10212 12764 4081050  1000
#  vec3  7294  8388 19983.63   8752 10576 3274759  1000
#  vec4 11670 12400 15423.03  12764 14223   74394  1000
#   lst 20787 21517 24561.72  21881 22975  143317  1000
#   env     0     1   461.25    365   366   18235  1000
```

Not surprisingly, the `list` does not perform well, though it seems to do better than the vectors (in the `max` case, relatively meaningless). Also not surprisingly, based on our claim that the environment uses an internal has, it performs quite well. Is it *O(1)*?

```
microbenchmark(
     samp5 = sapply(as.character(sample(5000, size =    5)), function(a) is.null(e[[a]])),
    samp50 = sapply(as.character(sample(5000, size =   50)), function(a) is.null(e[[a]])),
   samp500 = sapply(as.character(sample(5000, size =  500)), function(a) is.null(e[[a]])),
  samp5000 = sapply(as.character(sample(5000, size = 5000)), function(a) is.null(e[[a]]))
)
# Unit: microseconds
#      expr      min         lq        mean     median         uq       max neval
#     samp5   25.893    32.4565    49.58154    40.4795    58.3485   169.573   100
#    samp50  108.309   119.4310   156.45244   135.8410   167.3850   681.938   100
#   samp500  935.750  1023.2715  1265.29732  1073.9610  1172.6055  6841.985   100
#  samp5000 9410.008 10337.5520 11137.82968 10650.0765 11280.0485 15455.548   100
```

The first one, `samp5`, appears to take a bit longer. This isn't too surprising, since there is overhead associated with `sapply`, sampling, and other things. However, the remaining rows seem to scale somewhat well with the numbers of samples done. This suggests it is indeed *O(1)* for some basic set operations.

NB: I had to use the whole `sapply(...)` trick because, unlike vectors and lists, R's environments do not allow subsetting with a vector.

```
e[[c("1")]]
# [1] TRUE
e[[c("1","10")]]
# Error in e[[c("1", "10")]] : 
#   wrong arguments for subsetting an environment
```

This is one of the claims made by (and fixed by) `hashmap`.

Extra credit: in order to facilitate using an environment as a set, you could use simple adders and deleters:

```
newset <- function() new.env(parent = emptyenv())
setadd <- function(set, n) set[[n]] <- TRUE
setdel <- function(set, n) set[[n]] <- NULL
setcontains <- function(set, n) !is.null(set[[n]])
setmembers <- function(set) names(set)

e <- newset()
setcontains(e, "a")
# [1] FALSE
setadd(e, "a")
setcontains(e, "a")
# [1] TRUE
setmembers(e)
# [1] "a"
setdel(e, "a")
setcontains(e, "a")
# [1] FALSE
```

(There is a similar but much more extensive blog post on this by Jeffrey Horner here: http://jeffreyhorner.tumblr.com/post/114524915928/hash-table-performance-in-r-part-i.)

Comment: Awesome, very thorough.  But complicated.  Still wish there was a set() equivalent in R that was easy to use.  I guess R was primarily made for stats, not really programming per se.

Comment: But I think in some other languages like C#, I think you have to use a hashmap as well.